# Only getting last record from mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am stuck on a code where I want to fetch data from MySQL into an array.. I have a form containing color and size select boxes, an `onclick` javascript function is triggered and it created two more select boxes like above, I have managed to get data into the javascript code where the code for creating new select boxes is written. 
But I am only getting the last inserted record from both the tables. Although I have used a `while` loop.
Can someone help me out and I am also getting name of all select boxes likes `name="color[]"` , I want to insert records into a bridge table containing ids of color and size. below is my code please help ..

I will clear it up , each time I click add more button it should create 2 new dropdown lists, one for color and 2nd for size, both dropdowns should have the distinct data from database. so the ids for each record would be same in every dropdown list, I want to add more than 1 records in bridge table which contains product_id,color_id and size_id, so if I go for 3 dropwdown boxes , and i select blue color and small size in the first, then for second dropdown i again select blue color and size medium, as for the last dropdown which was also generated by the javascript function . i choose black color and large size. so from the dropdown it will get ids of size,color and it would be inserted accordingly.. so when i display the product and color blue is selected i would only see the sizes which were added to the color blue at the time of adding the product.. i hope this clears everything :)

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM color,size");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    ?>


    <script>
        var room = 1;
        function add_fields() {
            room++;
            var objTo = document.getElementById('room_fileds')
            var divtest = document.createElement("div");
            divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="label">Room ' + room + ':</div><div class="content"><span>Color: <select name="color[]"><option value="<?php echo $row['color_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['color']; ?></option></select></span><span>Size: <select><option value="<?php echo $row['size_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['size']; ?></option></select></span></div>';

            objTo.appendChild(divtest)
        }
    </script>

<?php

}
```

HTML code

```
<div id="room_fileds">
    <div>
        <div class='label'></div>
        <div class="content">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="more_fields" onclick="add_fields();" value="Add More" /> <br /><br />

            <select name="color[]"  class="form-control">
                <option value="0">Select Color</option>
                <?php
                $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM color");
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['color_id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['color']; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>

            <select name="size[]"  class="form-control">
                <option value="0">Select Size</option>
                <?php
                $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM size");
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['size_id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['size']; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your first code with the following:

```
<script>

var colors = [];
var sizes = [];
var room = 1;
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM color");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    colors.push(['<?php echo $row['color_id'] ?>', '<?php echo $row['color'] ?>']);
<?php }
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM size");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    sizes.push(['<?php echo $row['size_id'] ?>', '<?php echo $row['size'] ?>']);
<?php } ?>

function add_fields() {
    room++;
    var objTo = document.getElementById('room_fileds');
    var divtest = document.createElement("div");
    var html = '<div class="label">Room ' + room + ':</div><div class="content"><span>Color: <select name="color[]" class="form-control">';
    for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        html += '<option value="' + colors[i][0] + '">' + colors[i][1] + '</option>';
    }
    html += '</select></span><span>Size: <select name="size[]" class="form-control">';
    for (i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++) {
        html += '<option value="' + sizes[i][0] + '">' + sizes[i][1] + '</option>';
    }
    html += '</select></span></div>';
    divtest.innerHTML = html;
    objTo.appendChild(divtest);
    room++;
}

</script>
```

Comment: added your code bro, it displays only one row of data that is the first record, when i click the add more button it adds new fields but now it takes second row data for both fields ( color and size) i want to display all rows data in the select box. the reason for this is for eg: blue color jeans would have more than 1 sizes available in store.

Comment: Then I misunderstood your requirement, just to clarify, each time you click the button, you want to insert a new dropdown list with all the values or to append all the values to the existing dropdown list? If you can edit your question and rephrase your requirements that would be great :)

Comment: Thank you, and I updated my answer accordingly, hoping that is what you need :)

Comment: Thankyou bro, i checked the code it works just same as Nages code, the data displayed is being repeated 3 times...

Comment: Now I see, of course it gonna show duplicate repeated results for since it is a join query, therefore, you need to have two queries, one for sizes and one for colors, I have updated my answer accordingly :)

Comment: Awesome .. it worked ... Thanks a ton.. just one more thing i need to know .. as i explained in my question .. im getting the values now so i should simple use the insert query and the records will be added accordingly ? or do i have to work on something more ? marking your answer as accepted..

Comment: If I get you right, you need to use something like this `foreach($_POST['color'] as $key => $color) /* or $_GET['color'] depending on the form method */ { /* your insert statement , size can be accessed by $_POST['size'][$key] */ } `

Comment: yes i would like to insert the values into a bridge tables named bridge which contains following columns (bridge_id,color_id,size_id) .. how would i get color[] and size[] fields so to insert them into the database.. will it be like foreach for color and size like u mentioned above `$_POST['color'][$key]`    ` $_POST['size'][$key]`

Comment: Exactly! Or just `$color` instead of `$_POST['color'][$key]`

Comment: thanks a ton , im trying it now .. hopefully it would work as expected !!

Answer (score 0):

```
$divs='';
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM color,size");
$room=1;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $divs.='<div><div class="label">Room ' . $room . ':</div><div class="content"><span>Color: <select name="color[]"><option value="'.$row['color_id'].'">'.$row['color'].'</option></select></span><span>Size: <select><option value="'.$row['size_id'].'">'.$row['size'].'</option></select></span></div></div>';
    $room++;
} ?>
<script>
function add_fields() {          
    var objTo = document.getElementById('room_fileds');
    objTo.appendChild(<?php echo $divs; ?>);
}
</script>
```

Comment: hey check your while loop you are trying to concatenate 'room' using +

Comment: @Disha V thankyou for your code but i am getting                                            Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'color_id' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\jeans\admin\addedit_product.php on line 11   ....

Comment: @NageswaraRao i dont have any while loop in javascript , i also added `$i =1;` in php code before while loop .. then echo $i in `color[<?php echo $i; ?>]` .. and at last after while loop } $i++ ; but it gives me `color[21]` value for all the divs

Comment: @BabarAli , I Commented on disha's answer not on ur question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code hope it works for you

```
 <script>
var room = 1;
function add_fields() { 
    room++;  
    var objTo = document.getElementById('room_fileds');
    var divtest = document.createElement("div");
    <?php 
        $div_start='<div class="label">Room '."'+ room +'".' :</div><div class="content">';
        $color='<span>Color: <select name="color[]">';
        $size='<span>Size: <select>'
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM color,size");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
             $color.='<option value="'.$row['color_id'].'">'.$row['color'].'</option>';
             $size.='<option value="'.$row['size_id'].'">'.$row['size']'.</option>';
        }
        $color.='</select> </span>';
        $size.='</select> </span>';
        $div_close='</div>';
        $innerHTML=$div_start.$color.$size.$div_close; 
    ?> 
    divtest.innerHTML ='<?php echo $innerHTML; ?>';
    objTo.appendChild(divtest);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thankyou i do not get any error but when i click the add more button which has the onclick function triggered it does nothing.. No new fields are being generated..

Comment: are you getting any console errors? if any please comment I will edit accordingly

Comment: sorry I found something wrong in my code.. Now edited the answer Check it. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thankyou very much Nages , now data is being displayed but only one issue that is it is reapeating all all rows 3 times, for example color: `blue,blue,blue,black,black,black` ... although there is only one record of blue and black... same goes for size..can you please also guide me on the color name issue.. `name="color[]"` this is what i am getting in every `value`.. but i do get values according to their ids, would i be able to insert data into the bridge table like this ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code , it would help if anyone wants to code a similar thing.. just change values and it would work as per your need... and i would like to thank all people who replied to the thread and specially  Mohammad Anini .. it wouldnt have been possible without his help !!!

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (product_name,product_description, product_pic1, product_pic2, product_pic3,product_price,category_id,subcategory_id,product_status,color,size,product_slug, meta_keywords,entrydate)

                VALUES ('$product', '$description' , '$image', '$image2', '$image3', '$product_price', '$category', '$subcategory', '$product_status', '$capture_field_vals', '$size', '$product_slug1', '$meta_keywords', Now() )") or die(mysql_error());

                if ($query === TRUE) {

                    $lastid = mysql_insert_id();

                    $color["color"]=array();
                    $size["size"]=array();

                    foreach ($_POST['color'] as $key => $colorvalue) {
                    }


                    foreach ($_POST['size'] as $key => $sizevalue) {
                    }
                    $cid=array();
                    foreach($color as $rec){
                        $cid[]=$rec;
                    }
                    $sz=array();
                    foreach($size as $rec){
                        $sz[]=$rec;
                    }

                    $length=sizeof($color);
                    for($i=0;$i<$length-1;$i++){


                        $query2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO bridge (product_id,color_id, size_id)

                VALUES ('$lastid', '$cid[$i]' , '$sz[$i]')") or die(mysql_error());

                    // echo "<script>alert('New Product successfully Addedd');windows.location.replace('addedit_product.php');</script>";
                    }
```